# Click file:// url does not download the file in browser?

Tags: html, asp.net

We have a software on server A (`192.168.1.10`) and generates an excel file (`123.xlsx`), now, we have a asp.net website on server B. The site generates a link for that file:

```
<a target='_blank' href='file://192.168.1.10/share/123(copy 1).xlsx'>Data</a>
```

When the page loads, click the link, for some reasons, the browser does not either asks whether save the file or shows the file directly.

However, if I put the url in browser directly, it works.

What causes this? How to make it works for clicking?

Comment: What URL? What browser? Where is this file? What computer are you accessing it on? These are typically local only, they won't work on other machines.

Comment: See the link in the post. It is a file href. The click in browser does not work, but the url works if put in the browser directly.

Comment: URL encoding FTW.

Comment: This is just how browsers work when encountering a file-type they can't render in-browser. Also I hope you can come up with a filename without brackets or spaces. That's just plan messy.

Comment: you need to URL encode the href value using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` which, among others, converts space to `%20`.

Comment: tried: file://192.168.1.10/share/123_copy1.xlsx , file:///192.168.1.10/share/123_copy1).xlsx , both do not work in browser as link. Encoded them, do not work

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. If you search the web for "browser not opening file:// links" shows that this is because of security reasons. If you want to offer the file for download, you'll have to create a page that downloads the file from the remote server and offers it for download to the client.

Answer (score -1):

You can compress the excel in a zip file and allow the user to download from another server.

Here is the example to use Sharpziplib to zip the file. https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples